# Group wise matching in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, optimization, data-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe which has two columns. The first column represents `name` of the item and the second column represents some of its properties that are coded as integers. There can be multiple properties corresponding to an item. Here is a sample

```
    name                ids
0   A                   147 616 813
1   B                   51 616 13 813
2   C                   776
3   D                   51 671 13 813 1092
4   E                   13 404 492 903 1093
```

There are 300 such unique properties encoded as integers and then represented in a strings in the `id` column. What I want to achieve:

1. For each id find the rows where it occurs. For example, in order to check for `id` 13, I would fetch the rows `1, 3 and 4`.
2. What are all the unique ids that came up with this id in our dataset? For example, I would say that for id `13: [51, 616, 813, 671, 1092, 404, 492, 903, 1093]`
3. Once we have the grouped rows for each id, how can I compare whether a given id is in that group or not? For example, I want to check if the id `52` ever occurred with id `13` and if yes, where and how many times?

I have been thinking about this long but couldn't come with an efficient method to get the first two and an efficient way as well as DS for 3). Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution Without using any for loop

```
import pandas as pd
import numpu as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':'A B C D E'
                   .split(),'ids':['147 616 813','51 616 13 813','776','51 671 13 813 1092','13 404 492 903 1093']})

#Every input of i_d to functions in int
#to get indexes where id occurs
def rows(i_d):
    i_d = str(i_d)
    pattern1 = "[^0-9]" +i_d+"[^0-9]"
    pattern2 = i_d+"[^0-9]"    
    pattern3 = "[^0-9]" +i_d 

    mask = df.ids.apply(lambda x: True if (len(re.findall(pattern1,x)) > 0) | (len(re.findall(pattern2,x))) | (len(re.findall(pattern3,x)) > 0) else False)

    return df[mask].index.tolist()

#to get other ids occuring with the id in discussion
def colleagues(i_d):
    i_d = str(i_d)

    df.loc[rows(i_d),'temp'] = 1
    k =list(set(df.groupby('temp').ids.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).iloc[0].split()))
    k.remove(i_d)
    df.drop('temp',axis=1,inplace=True)

    return k

#to get row indexes where 2 ids occur together
def third(i_d1,i_d2):
    i_d1 = str(i_d1)
    i_d2 = str(i_d2)

    common_rows = list(np.intersect1d(rows(i_d1),rows(i_d2)))
    if len(common_rows) > 0:
        return print('Occured together at rows ',common_rows)
    else:
        return print("Didn't occur together")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `for` loop is nowhere an efficient way

Comment: @mlRocks Check out this updated code, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal for the three functions:

```
import pandas as pd
# first we create the data
data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A','B','C','D','E'],
                'ids': ['147 616 813','51 616 13 813','776','51 671 13 813 
1092','13 404 492 903 1093']})

def func1(num, series):
    # num must be an int
    # series a Pandas series
    tx = series.apply(lambda x: True if str(num) in x.split() else False)

    output_list = series.index[tx].tolist()

    return output_list

 def func2(num, series):
    # num must be an int
    # series a Pandas series
    series = series.iloc[func1(num, series)]

    series = series.apply(lambda x: x.split()).tolist()

    output_list = set([item for sublist in series for item in sublist])
    output_list.remove(str(num))
    return list(output_list)

def func3(num1,num2,series):
    # num1 must be an int
    # num2 must be an int
    # series a Pandas series

    if str(num1) in func2(num2, series):
        num1_index = func1(num1, series)
        num2_index = func1(num2, series)
        return list(set(num1_index) & set(num2_index))
    else:
        return 'no match'
```

and then you could test them:

```
func1(13, data['ids'])
func2(13, data['ids'])
func3(13,51,data['ids'])
```